# Kivy-ios: Toolchain build fails when trying to build kivy

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I'm trying to package my app for iOS. I am following the instructions on Kivy's official site. When I run `toolchain build kivy`, the build fails and shows the following error:

```
[DEBUG   ] /Users/rehatbir/Dev/Python/STEM-Project/client/build/hostpython3/x86_64/Python-3.8.2/Modules/posixmodule.c:9197:15: error:
[DEBUG   ]       implicit declaration of function 'sendfile' is invalid in C99
[DEBUG   ]       [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
[DEBUG   ]         ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);
```

I am using macOS Big Sur, I have seen people downgrading to Catalina to fix this but I do not have a backup of my computer on Catalina and I don't have the disk space to make a virtual machine and install Xcode on it. Please help me.